# Convert document to PDF from right-click context menu

Tags: finder, pdf, contextual-menu

Sometimes I have doc and txt files that I need to convert to PDF. It'd be great if I didn't have to open an application to convert the item to PDF. Is there some way to add a convert/print to PDF option in Finder's right-click context menu?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any app like that. You can simply to convert any .doc to .pdf over the internet, on several websites.